# Convert Pandas Object to Array

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I have a column in dataframe which is of the type object. I want to convert it to an array.
ex:

```
'["399866273","12444645","162497334"]'
```

I am aware of converting it to string and splitting it based on `,`. But I want to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: If you mean a `numpy.ndarray` then you just want `my_df['column'].values`, if you want a *list*, then you just want `my_df['column'].to_list()`

Comment: I can't do this, it would say 'str' object has no attribute 'values' @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Then **you don't have a dataframe** you have `str`. How did you produce this string? You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Try dir(SomeObject) for the object you are getting. It may help determine what you're dealing with.

Comment: @Mike67  or just `type(my_object)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This is a column from a dataframe. When I do df.dtype it shows this columns as object.

Comment: @JohnConstantine then you aren't doing what I told you. Please, again, provide a [mcve] if you are indeed getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import json
import numpy as np

def toarray(s):
    x = json.loads(s)
    arr = np.array(x)
    return arr

# Test
s = '["399866273","12444645","162497334"]'
asset type(toarray(s)) == np.ndarray
assert all(toarray(s) == np.array(["399866273", "12444645", "162497334"]))

# Apply to df
colname = ...  # your col name
df['as_array'] = df[colname].apply(toarray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['["399866273","12444645","162497334"]'], columns = ['Column_ObjectType'])

df.dtypes
#output
Column_ObjectType    object
dtype: object

df[['Value1','Value2','Value3']] = df.Column_ObjectType.str.split(",", expand=True)
df.head()
#output
                      Column_ObjectType        Value1      Value2        Value3
0  ["399866273","12444645","162497334"]  ["399866273"  "12444645"  "162497334"]

df['Value1'] = df.Value1.apply(lambda x: x[2:-1])
df['Value2'] = df.Value1.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1])
df['Value3'] = df.Value1.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1])
df.head()
#output
                  Column_ObjectType     Value1    Value2    Value3
0  ["399866273","12444645","162497334"]  399866273  39986627  39986627
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a list you can just use `eval()`